# How to create custom endpoints on the fly with nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, endpoint

I have a website and when I click on a button I want to generate a custom link for the user, a link that it will be a endpoint to my nodejs server. My question is: how can this be accomplished ? I think I need to make a basic endpoint in my server that will be called when I press that button in my website and then, based on a custom property in the request's body, it will generate another endpoint, a custom endpoint for that user. How can I do this ? Any help or documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: like   "api/product:id" search for that or look on traversy media youtube toutorial

Comment: how is that "product:id" thing called ? so I can research it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, this would be done with a parameter added to a fixed part of the URL.  You then define a route for the fixed part of the URL and the code for that route then examines the parameter and acts accordingly.  This way, you're dynamically generating parameters, but all the new parameters all go through the same route definition and the same code.

You can either use a dynamic portion of the URL path or a query parameter.  Here is an example of each:

```
// dynamic path segment
// example url /dyn/dieutaoc
app.get("/dyn/:id", (req, res) => {
    // use req.params.id to access the dynamic part of this path
});

// dynamic query parameter
// example url /dyn?id=dieutaoc
app.get("/dyn", (req, res) => {
    // use req.query.id to access the dynamic part of this path
});
```